# URLが変わらない時のHTML取得

Tags: c#

```
webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted
```

でURLが変更した時の処理はできますが、URLが変更しない場合の処理はどうすれば取得できますか？
Timer以外の方法を模索しています。

Comment: 「URLが変更された時」でないなら、**どのタイミングで**HTMLを取得したいのでしょうか？一定時間後ならTimer等、ボタンを押されたときならそのボタン等に、イベントハンドラを設定するのが基本的なパターンかと思います。そして基本的にどのイベントでも `DocumentCompleted` 内と同じようにしてHTML取得ないしDOM操作が行えるはずです。

Comment: ショップサイトなどで画像を大量にアップロードすると時間がかかります、アップロード後に表示されるリンクを取得したいのですが、その時、URLが変わらないのでイベントが取れません。
Timerを使って5秒ごとに取得してますが、他の方法があれば知りたかったです。

Comment: @まめたろう それならアップロード処理の完了イベントを待ってはどうでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、アップロード完了処理はわかりませんでしたが`webBrowser1_Navigated`で済みました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
webBrowser1_Navigated
```

にしました